# How do you call FileManager.setAttributes()

Tags: ios, swift

I'm applying a code snippet from the Realm documentation (https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) but it doesn't compile

```
 try! FileManager.default.setAttributes([FileAttributeKey(rawValue: NSFileProtectionKey): NSFileProtectionNone], ofItemAtPath: folderPath)
```

What does this error mean

> Invalid initializer call with same type 'FileAttributeKey' as
>   parameter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to initiate a `FileAttributeKey` with the ObjC `NSFileProtectionKey`, which is of type `NSFileAttributeKey` aka same type as `FileAttributeKey`. Therefore no need to initiate one, just use `NSFileProtectionKey` on its own.

```
[NSFileProtectionKey: NSFileProtectionNone]
```

Depending on your Swift version, you may be told that the keys have been renamed.

```
let attributes = [ FileAttributeKey.protectionKey : FileProtectionType.none ]

try! FileManager.default.setAttributes(attributes)
```

The `setAttributes` method requires a value of type `[FileAttributeKey : Any]`, so if we pass the attributes directly as a dictionary, we can omit `FileAttributeKey` since the key type is inferred.

```
try! FileManager.default.setAttributes([.protectionKey: FileProtectionType.none], ofItemAtPath: folderPath)
```